# aws kinesis analytics - how to define partition key for destination stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

While using kinesis analytics, how it is possible to specify the partition key when output records are streamed to destination ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that amazon kinesis analytics for the time of writing doesn't provide possibility of controlling partition keys while writing to destination stream.
It will create some internal partition keys and push the records to the downstream according to these keys.